# Determining whether query will change DB

Tags: java, database, jdbc

How can I determine that particular query will change the state of DB?
I use JDBC. Should I use parsing searching for key words like INSERT, DELETE or there are some other ways?

Comment: Do you care if the statement is something that could change the database or do you want to know if something actually will change?

Comment: The first case. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would like to know that? Do you plan to let end users enter SQL queries directly?

Comment: I want to ask user whether he really wants this query to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

1. [Execute the query](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)
2. Check the [update count](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29)
3. If updates are made, do your user check
4. On a positive response, [commit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) the transaction. On negative, [roll it back](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29).

There would be variations. Explore the [Statement API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) to get a feel for your options.

**Edit:** Ensure [autocommit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) is off, or transactionality is out the window!

**More edit:** As pointed out by commenters, this isn't a scalable solution. For scalability, transactions have to be kept short, and you don't want to have user think time during an open transaction. If there will be multiple users, find a way to do this that doesn't involve holding a transaction open, perhaps with some creative use of statement caching and rollbacks/commits. For better advice, explain more about your requirements.

Comment: Hmm that's still not a good solution because the user can hack by doing `SET autocommit = 1; .....` so this is not really safe. Up to you what you do though. It also performs bad because all other changes to the database are on hold until `commit`.

Comment: That's true if users can execute arbitrary queries, but I'm assuming that's not the case, else he's just writing a database browser. Performance could be a problem depending on concurrent usage. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Ryan: that's why I asked the OP why he wanted to do that. I don't knwo why it would be useful if he doesn't plan to let the user execute arbitrary queries. It seems to be the case, since he answered that he want to ask the user to confirm he really wants to execute the query.

Comment: @JB: True. I see your point. To me, if the user is assumed to be sophisticated enough to execute his own queries, then the onus is on him to use the tool properly. Showing a warning dialog in the case of autocommit being off should be sufficient for such a user. It's just a question of "how much rope".

Comment: This is VERY BAD PRACTICE! Never ask for user input in a transaction. An open transaction after a DML statement will keep a lock on tables and indexes and may block other processes completely. Worst case, you can actually take down your whole database, needing to close all connection or maybe even reboot the lot. Just don't! transactions should be left open as short as possible. You won't want to wait for a user who maybe is just getting a cup of coffee.

Comment: @Golez: It depends on the purpose of the application. Database explorers/workbenches do that (long transactions) all the time. I've added a caveat to my answer, though, to warn off the casual coder.

Comment: Database explorers don't keep a transaction open unless you tell them to. And these are usually developement databases with fewer users and less heavy load.

Comment: @Golez: Those are very broad statements. Do you have any references to back them up? In the end, it really comes down to what the OP's requirements are, which he didn't really share.

Comment: Well, I got a ton of experience with Oracle myself, but look at this coding style guide by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187484.aspx "If additional user input is required during a transaction, roll back the current transaction and restart the transaction after the user input is supplied.  Even if users respond immediately, human reaction times are vastly slower than computer speeds. All resources held by the transaction are held for an extremely long time, which has the potential to cause blocking problems."

Comment: There are many guides to be found online which back up this story.Okay, I was probably exaggerating when I said your database would need a reboot. But deadlocks can pile up causing the database to be non-responsive to your users. You will have to kill a few transactions to fix this, and then you'll have to wait until queued requests are sorted out. OP didn't specify this explicitly, but I think a working database is in the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Don't check the query. Instead, make sure the query is run under user credentials that are not allowed to modify the database. You can create multiple users and grant each limited rights. This application should connect using the user that can only select data.

The exact way (and if this is possible at all) depends on the database you use, but I think every modern DBMS supports this.

You could execute the query, catch the exception that you'll probably get when the user has insufficient rights, and after confirmation you can connect using a different user. This way you leave it all to the database and its rights management, which it much more secure and less error prone than parsing the queries yourself.

Comment: I asked what I asked. Thank you, I know about different roles and assigning user to them. But it's not the question.

Comment: Rather than answering your question, I thought I'd provide you with a solution for your problem. I've made a little addition that might be helpful, but if you rather parse your queries yourself, please go ahead. But you'll need to have quite some knowledge of SQL to do this right. A select query does not necessarily start with select, and delete and insert statements can contain a select as well. And those are only the common exceptions...

Comment: Thank you, I supposed that only way is to parse. But hoped that it's not.

Comment: You guys aren't answering his question as given. @damluar: check my answer

Comment: @Ryan. And yes, you do answer the question but following your answer might kill his database.

Comment: I too agree with Golez. The right approach is to use the db read/write permission. The OP should really reevaluate the use case.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest doing this with MySQL permissions. Have two users, one with read only access and with read/write.

1. Execute the query with read only user
2. Check for SQLException and if one is thrown then show your message if they really want to write
3. Then use the second user.

This I think is the safest way because you are pushing the permission on the database. Otherwise you would have to have a sophisticated sql parser which could be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. An `UPDATE` or `DELETE` *might* change the DB. If you want to know **whether it might** change the database, a case-insensitive search for the `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `ALTER` keywords will tell you there's a possibility of the query changing the database. Although there's nothing preventing something like `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE something = 'update'`, so watch out for that.

If you want to know **whether a change will actually be made**, *before running the query*, you're going to have to know something about the data already in the database. Do a `SELECT` using the same `WHERE` clause as the potentially data-altering `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement, and compare the data, for example (this could get messy for queries that use `JOIN` or other more advanced features of SQL). An easier way would be to [use transactions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) to make the change, check for change, and then roll back the transaction, undoing the changes.

If you want to **prevent changes**, as other answers suggest you should make use of your DBMS's role-management, and don't grant permission to execute altering queries to the user or role running these queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JDBC expert, but I had seen this and could be helpful to you:

http://www.techfeed.net/blog/index.cfm/2006/4/20/Obtaining-Affected-rows-from-SQL-Query

It gives some techniques for retrieving the number of rows affected by INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. Of course, that isn't of much help for CREATE/DROP TABLE, etc. But it's a start.

Comment: Ah, just saw that you want to intercept the statement *before* it executes. Never mind, then! (these would work AFTER executing).